# Firebase Cloud Functions deply error in React Native - Conflicts in the file and redeclaration errors

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deply basic cloud function, in React Native, to an existing firebase web-app that I already use with another web application. `firebase deploy` command works successfully in the web application, however in RN, deployment fails with a lot of errors. Almost all errors are about conflicts and redeclarations inside files in node_modules. I removed the functions folder and re-initialised, but still not working.

Here's the code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from Firebase!");
})
```

Error:

```
../node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:473:14 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'error' must be of type 'DOMException | null', but here has type 'Error | null'.

473     readonly error: Error | null;
                 ~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5368:14
    5368     readonly error: DOMException | null;
                      ~~~~~
    'error' was also declared here.

../node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:481:14 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'result' must be of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null', but here has type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.

481     readonly result: string | ArrayBuffer;
                 ~~~~~~

.......

179 declare var Request: {
                ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:11731:13
    11731 declare var Request: {
                      ~~~~~~~
    'Request' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:184:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.

184 declare type RequestInfo = Request | string;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:18345:6
    18345 type RequestInfo = Request | string;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'RequestInfo' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:187:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'headers' must be of type 'HeadersInit | undefined', but here has type 'HeadersInit_ | undefined'.

187   headers?: HeadersInit_ | undefined;
      ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:1623:5
    1623     headers?: HeadersInit;
             ~~~~~~~
    'headers' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:203:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Response' must be of type '{ new (body?: BodyInit | null | undefined, init?: ResponseInit | undefined): Response; prototype: Response; error(): Response; redirect(url: string | URL, status?: number | undefined): Response; }', but here has type '{ new (body?: BodyInit_ | undefined, init?: ResponseInit | undefined): Response; prototype: Response; error: () => Response; redirect: (url: string, status?: number | undefined) => Response; }'.

203 declare var Response: {
                ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:11782:13
    11782 declare var Response: {
                      ~~~~~~~~
    'Response' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:265:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'DONE' must be of type 'number', but here has type '4'.

265   readonly DONE: 4;
               ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17165:14
    17165     readonly DONE: number;
                       ~~~~
    'DONE' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:266:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'HEADERS_RECEIVED' must be of type 'number', but here has type '2'.

266   readonly HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17166:14
    17166     readonly HEADERS_RECEIVED: number;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'HEADERS_RECEIVED' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:267:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'LOADING' must be of type 'number', but here has type '3'.

267   readonly LOADING: 3;
               ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17167:14
    17167     readonly LOADING: number;
                       ~~~~~~~
    'LOADING' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:268:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'OPENED' must be of type 'number', but here has type '1'.

268   readonly OPENED: 1;
               ~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17168:14
    17168     readonly OPENED: number;
                       ~~~~~~
    'OPENED' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:269:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'UNSENT' must be of type 'number', but here has type '0'.

269   readonly UNSENT: 0;
               ~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17169:14
    17169     readonly UNSENT: number;
                       ~~~~~~
    'UNSENT' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:282:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'XMLHttpRequest' must be of type '{ new (): XMLHttpRequest; prototype: XMLHttpRequest; readonly DONE: number; readonly HEADERS_RECEIVED: number; readonly LOADING: number; readonly OPENED: number; readonly UNSENT: number; }', but here has type '{ new (): XMLHttpRequest; prototype: XMLHttpRequest; readonly DONE: 4; readonly HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2; readonly LOADING: 3; readonly OPENED: 1; readonly UNSENT: 0; }'.

282 declare var XMLHttpRequest: {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17176:13
    17176 declare var XMLHttpRequest: {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'XMLHttpRequest' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:293:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'abort' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

293   abort: ProgressEvent;
      ~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17187:5
    17187     "abort": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~
    'abort' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:294:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'error' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

294   error: ProgressEvent;
      ~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17188:5
    17188     "error": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~
    'error' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:295:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'load' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

295   load: ProgressEvent;
      ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17189:5
    17189     "load": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~
    'load' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:296:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'loadend' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

296   loadend: ProgressEvent;
      ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17190:5
    17190     "loadend": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~
    'loadend' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:297:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'loadstart' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

297   loadstart: ProgressEvent;
      ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17191:5
    17191     "loadstart": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'loadstart' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:298:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'progress' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

298   progress: ProgressEvent;
      ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17192:5
    17192     "progress": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~
    'progress' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:299:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'timeout' must be of type 'ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>', but here has type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>'.

299   timeout: ProgressEvent;
      ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:17193:5
    17193     "timeout": ProgressEvent<XMLHttpRequestEventTarget>;
              ~~~~~~~~~
    'timeout' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:352:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.

352 declare type XMLHttpRequestResponseType =
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:18505:6
    18505 type XMLHttpRequestResponseType = "" | "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "document" | "json" | "text";
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'XMLHttpRequestResponseType' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:365:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URL'.

365 declare class URL {
                  ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:14499:11
    14499 interface URL {
                    ~~~
    'URL' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:14516:13
    14516 declare var URL: {
                      ~~~
    and here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:390:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.

390 declare class URLSearchParams {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:14526:11
    14526 interface URLSearchParams {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'URLSearchParams' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:14545:13
    14545 declare var URLSearchParams: {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.iterable.d.ts:263:11
    263 interface URLSearchParams {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:448:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onopen' must be of type '((this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any) | null', but here has type '(() => void) | null'.

448   onopen: (() => void) | null;
      ~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16721:5
    16721     onopen: ((this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any) | null;
              ~~~~~~
    'onopen' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:449:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onmessage' must be of type '((this: WebSocket, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any) | null', but here has type '((event: WebSocketMessageEvent) => void) | null'.

449   onmessage: ((event: WebSocketMessageEvent) => void) | null;
      ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16720:5
    16720     onmessage: ((this: WebSocket, ev: MessageEvent) => any) | null;
              ~~~~~~~~~
    'onmessage' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:450:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onerror' must be of type '((this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any) | null', but here has type '((event: WebSocketErrorEvent) => void) | null'.

450   onerror: ((event: WebSocketErrorEvent) => void) | null;
      ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16719:5
    16719     onerror: ((this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any) | null;
              ~~~~~~~
    'onerror' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:451:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onclose' must be of type '((this: WebSocket, ev: CloseEvent) => any) | null', but here has type '((event: WebSocketCloseEvent) => void) | null'.

451   onclose: ((event: WebSocketCloseEvent) => void) | null;
      ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16718:5
    16718     onclose: ((this: WebSocket, ev: CloseEvent) => any) | null;
              ~~~~~~~
    'onclose' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:452:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'addEventListener' must be of type '{ <K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void; (type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | ... 1 more ... | undefined): void; }', but here has type 'WebsocketEventListener'.

452   addEventListener: WebsocketEventListener;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16736:5
    16736     addEventListener<K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'addEventListener' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:453:3 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'removeEventListener' must be of type '{ <K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions | undefined): void; (type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | ... 1 more ... | undefined): void; }', but here has type 'WebsocketEventListener'.

453   removeEventListener: WebsocketEventListener;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16738:5
    16738     removeEventListener<K extends keyof WebSocketEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: WebSocket, ev: WebSocketEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'removeEventListener' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:456:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'WebSocket' must be of type '{ new (url: string | URL, protocols?: string | string[] | undefined): WebSocket; prototype: WebSocket; readonly CLOSED: number; readonly CLOSING: number; readonly CONNECTING: number; readonly OPEN: number; }', but here has type '{ new (uri: string, protocols?: string | string[] | null | undefined, options?: { [optionName: string]: any; headers: { [headerName: string]: string; }; } | null | undefined): WebSocket; ... 4 more ...; readonly OPEN: number; }'.

456 declare var WebSocket: {
                ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16742:13
    16742 declare var WebSocket: {
                      ~~~~~~~~~
    'WebSocket' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:480:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'AbortSignal'.

480 declare class AbortSignal implements EventTarget {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2059:11
    2059 interface AbortSignal extends EventTarget {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'AbortSignal' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2071:13
    2071 declare var AbortSignal: {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.
  node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:60:11
    60 interface AbortSignal extends EventTarget {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.
  node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:77:13
    77 declare var AbortSignal: typeof globalThis extends {onmessage: any; AbortSignal: infer T}
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:480:15 - error TS2420: Class 'AbortSignal' incorrectly implements interface 'EventTarget'.
  Property 'dispatchEvent' is missing in type 'AbortSignal' but required in type 'EventTarget'.

480 declare class AbortSignal implements EventTarget {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5309:5
    5309     dispatchEvent(event: Event): boolean;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'dispatchEvent' is declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:515:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'AbortController'.

515 declare class AbortController {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2042:11
    2042 interface AbortController {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'AbortController' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2049:13
    2049 declare var AbortController: {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.
  node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:47:11
    47 interface AbortController {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.
  node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:70:13
    70 declare var AbortController: typeof globalThis extends {onmessage: any; AbortController: infer T}
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    and here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:540:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'error' must be of type 'DOMException | null', but here has type 'Error | null'.

540   readonly error: Error | null;
               ~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5368:14
    5368     readonly error: DOMException | null;
                      ~~~~~
    'error' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:550:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'result' must be of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null', but here has type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.

550   readonly result: string | ArrayBuffer;
               ~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5376:14
    5376     readonly result: string | ArrayBuffer | null;
                      ~~~~~~
    'result' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:556:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'DONE' must be of type 'number', but here has type '2'.

556   readonly DONE: 2;
               ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5382:14
    5382     readonly DONE: number;
                      ~~~~
    'DONE' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:557:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'EMPTY' must be of type 'number', but here has type '0'.

557   readonly EMPTY: 0;
               ~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5383:14
    5383     readonly EMPTY: number;
                      ~~~~~
    'EMPTY' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:558:12 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'LOADING' must be of type 'number', but here has type '1'.

558   readonly LOADING: 1;
               ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5384:14
    5384     readonly LOADING: number;
                      ~~~~~~~
    'LOADING' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:573:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'FileReader' must be of type '{ new (): FileReader; prototype: FileReader; readonly DONE: number; readonly EMPTY: number; readonly LOADING: number; }', but here has type '{ new (): FileReader; prototype: FileReader; readonly DONE: 2; readonly EMPTY: 0; readonly LOADING: 1; }'.

573 declare var FileReader: {
                ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5391:13
    5391 declare var FileReader: {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~
    'FileReader' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/LaunchScreen.d.ts:13:16 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Header'.

13   export const Header: any;
                  ~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/LaunchScreen.d.ts:4:18
    4     export const Header: any;
                       ~~~~~~
    'Header' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/LaunchScreen.d.ts:14:16 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'LearnMoreLinks'.

14   export const LearnMoreLinks: any;
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/LaunchScreen.d.ts:5:18
    5     export const LearnMoreLinks: any;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LearnMoreLinks' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/LaunchScreen.d.ts:15:16 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Colors'.

15   export const Colors: any;
                  ~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/LaunchScreen.d.ts:6:18
    6     export const Colors: any;
                       ~~~~~~
    'Colors' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/LaunchScreen.d.ts:16:16 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'DebugInstructions'.

16   export const DebugInstructions: any;
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/LaunchScreen.d.ts:7:18
    7     export const DebugInstructions: any;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'DebugInstructions' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/LaunchScreen.d.ts:17:16 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ReloadInstructions'.

17   export const ReloadInstructions: any;
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/LaunchScreen.d.ts:8:18
    8     export const ReloadInstructions: any;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'ReloadInstructions' was also declared here.

../node_modules/react-native/types/public/DeprecatedPropertiesAlias.d.ts:10:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: TextProperties, TextPropertiesIOS, TextPropertiesAndroid, AccessibilityProperties, AccessibilityPropertiesIOS, AccessibilityPropertiesAndroid, TextInputProperties, TextInputIOSProperties, TextInputAndroidProperties, ViewProperties, ViewPropertiesIOS, ViewPropertiesAndroid, ScrollViewProperties, ScrollViewPropertiesIOS, ScrollViewPropertiesAndroid, InputAccessoryViewProperties, ActivityIndicatorProperties, ActivityIndicatorIOSProperties, DrawerLayoutAndroidProperties, ProgressBarAndroidProperties, RefreshControlProperties, RefreshControlPropertiesIOS, RefreshControlPropertiesAndroid, ImagePropertiesSourceOptions, ImageProperties, ImagePropertiesIOS, ImagePropertiesAndroid, ImageBackgroundProperties, FlatListProperties, VirtualizedListProperties, SectionListProperties, ModalProperties, TouchableWithoutFeedbackProperties, TouchableHighlightProperties, TouchableOpacityProperties, TouchableNativeFeedbackProperties, ButtonProperties, StatusBarProperties, StatusBarPropertiesIOS, StatusBarPropertiesAndroid, SwitchProperties, SwitchPropertiesIOS

10 import {
   ~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/legacy-properties.d.ts:1:1
    1 import {
      ~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.


Found 156 errors in 19 files.

Errors  Files
     4  node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:47
    12  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2042
     2  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.iterable.d.ts:86
     1  ../node_modules/@types/react-native-vector-icons/Icon.d.ts:8
     3  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/BatchedBridge.d.ts:8
     1  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/Codegen.d.ts:1
     1  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/Devtools.d.ts:2
    45  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:10
     5  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts:9939
     5  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/LaunchScreen.d.ts:4
    15  ../node_modules/@types/react-native/legacy-properties.d.ts:1
     1  ../node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/global.d.ts:152
     5  ../node_modules/react-native/types/index.d.ts:200
     3  ../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/BatchedBridge.d.ts:17
     1  ../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/Codegen.d.ts:10
     1  ../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/Devtools.d.ts:11
    45  ../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/globals.d.ts:19
     5  ../node_modules/react-native/types/modules/LaunchScreen.d.ts:13
     1  ../node_modules/react-native/types/public/DeprecatedPropertiesAlias.d.ts:10

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: If I delete node_modules (root directory) before deploying, it works. It looks like type conflict inside type definition files.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding this line to the tsconfig.json in your functions folder.

"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],